# How to create MPMediaItem from assetURL!.absoluteString?

Tags: swift, mpmediaitem, mpmediapickercontroller, mpmediaitemcollection

I am saving `(mediaItemCollection.items.first?.assetURL!.absoluteString)` to local SQLite DB as String. 
Now I want to create MPMediaItem object back from saved string i.e `assetURL!.absoluteString`, Is it possible to create MPMediaItem object from its assesURL? If it is not possible then what should I save to SQLite DB so that I can create object of MPMediaItem back from saved property?

Comment: For a local file URL `absoluteString` is the wrong API anyway.

Comment: `assetURL` contains `persistentID`, and you may query by it. But you definetely should store some other info instead of `url`

Comment: hey @user28434 and @vadian any Idea what should use instead of ```absoluteString``` ?

Comment: In my project I'm saving info about song itself. Like `Name` and `Artists`, etc. But only because in my project user can share info about media between their devices, and `persistentID`(and `assetURL`) are completely different on different devices. And I'm using it to query `MPMediaItem`. But in your case, if "reference" to the media will never leave the device you can just store `persistentID`.

Comment: Hey @user28434 Can you explain how to query by ```persistentID```?  I could not find the way to do that.

Comment: Using [MPMediaQuery](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpmediaquery) with [MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpmediaitempropertypersistentid) in the predicate.

Comment: Thanks  @user28434 I solved the problem from your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have find the solution from @user28434 suggestion.

I am saving persistentID to SQLite DB as String

```swift
 let songItem = mediaItemCollection.representativeItem!
 let persistantID = String(songItem.persistentID)
```

From this `persistentID` I am able to create `MPMediaItem` object back using `MPMediaQuery`  while fetching stored `persistentID` from DB.

Following way to create `MPMediaItem` object.

```swift
 let noCloudPre = MPMediaPropertyPredicate(value: NSNumber(booleanLiteral: false),
                                              forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyIsCloudItem)

    func getSongItem(persistantID: String) -> MPMediaItem?{
        let songQuery = MPMediaQuery.songs()
        songQuery.addFilterPredicate(noCloudPre)
        songQuery.addFilterPredicate(MPMediaPropertyPredicate(value: persistantID,
                                    forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID,
                                    comparisonType: MPMediaPredicateComparison.equalTo))
        return songQuery.items?[0]
    }
```

Comment: Storing it as a number would be more efficient